# Windows 8.1 locks account after 3 invalid attempts even if GP is not defined

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

I mistyped my password three times today, and my account became locked on my windows 8.1 pro workstation.  I checked Resultant Set of Policies (rsop.msc) and all three relevant settings are "Not Defined"

- Account lockout duration
- Account lockout threshold
- Reset account lockout counter after

"Account lockout threshold" defaults to "0" and "If you set the value to 0, the account will never be locked out."

Thanks

Update:

I ran gpresult /h [filename] and no lockout policy is defined at all (confirming all my other comments)

Comment: Is the machine domain-joined?

Comment: Yes, the machine is domain-joined.

Comment: Just because the local policy has a default value and are "Not Defined", a GPO configured and linked in the domain may still override that policy setting

Comment: Is the account stored on the local computer (accessible through Computer Management on your workstation) or in Active Directory?

Comment: active directory

Comment: Local policies do not affect Active Directory User Accounts.  You must set the policies of the Domain Controller, not the workstation you are logging in through.

Comment: Take the computer out of the equation, and just check at purely the domain level. Use group policy modeling see if the results you get there are the same as the gpresult on the computer.

Answer (score 3):

RSOP support has been deprecated.  According to http://deployhappiness.com/gpresult-or-rsop/

> "Beginning with Windows Vista SP1, Microsoft made the GPResult command
>   the primary tool for troubleshooting Group Policy on a client."

Basically, to ensure that you are getting the full result of policies on the machine, you need to use GPResult instead of RSOP.

However, your account is located on the Domain Controller, and therefore, the policy of the Domain applies to lockouts.  No amount of tweaking, configuring, or policy editing will change that on your local workstation.  Any time you enter your password, the Domain must authenticate it, and it will count towards your attempts.  Other things can count against your attempts as well, such as cached credentials, or being logged in to other computers with stale credentials.

This part is no longer relevant.

> Furthermore, the location of the account is incredibly important! 
>   **If the account is actually an Active Directory Domain account**, your local machine policies will NOT affect your account lockout,
>   **you will have to check the group policy settings of the domain controller** (e.g. run GPResult on the DC).  Accounts stored on the
>   domain don't authenticate against your computer, and the lockout is
>   triggered on the domain controller, not your local workstation. 
>   Accounts stored locally will follow the GPResult, but only after
>   you've rebooted the computer since the WinLogon service will have to
>   re-initialize with the new GPO settings.  (Not all GPO settings can be
>   applied without a reboot).

Comment: gpresult did indicate more GPO's that were impacting me, however, I manually edited each one (also reviewed a summary of each one in the "Settings" tab from Group Policy Management) and all of them are also not defined.

Answer (score 2):

For Group Policy "Not Defined" is NOT the same thing as "NOT SET", FALSE or any other meaning.

Not Defined means the group policy *at the level you are analyzing* makes no change to the Windows default.

You may also need to looks at
- is there a lower security scope (local on a non-domain member) that IS defined.

- What is the Windows Default action when this is not defined.
     I suspect it is to lockout but i'm not finding a concrete link I can refer you to.

Or you may want to jump straight to the answer:
- If for some reason you want to bypass this helpful security setting, set the Account lockout threshold to a higher number of errors and allow the protection to remain enabled .....

Comment: Good catch on "Not Defined" I completely missed that.  It also means other policies (such as network policies) can still be applied.

Comment: yes, but... if it's "not defined" then the default is what's used, right?  I mean... there's no other way for the "default" to be used...

Comment: Also, I tried setting it to 4 invalid attempts, and it still locked me out at 3 (after gpupdate /force).

Comment: NO, Group Policy is applied in a hierarchy, with the most specific policy always winning.  Local Computer policies that are set will override network policies (in most cases), but if not set can be either the default, or the setting of another policy that applies to the computer and/or user.

Comment: local computer policy is set to "0 invalid login attempts" meaning "Account will not lock out", all other policies that do apply (via gpresult) have it "not defined"

Comment: Local policies do not affect domain accounts.

Comment: @Novox  -- if indeed you set the policy to 4, or 10, or more attempts nd it still locked out at 3 attempts, then the policy you are changing is NOT is scope and is having no effect - be careful - this same bag of rights exists at multiple levels (machine, domain, forest at least).

Comment: I know local policy and domain policy are different, I was trying to explain that both are set to 0... (either explicitly or by default)...

Comment: @IceMage - its been some time since "...the most specific policy always winning."  Ever since Microsoft added the "precedence" value to the GPO and PSC objects the admin can construct some bizarre precedence trees that defy assumptions.   Use the proper tool for your O/S version to compute the RSOP, regardless of its name this week to see the forest wide settigns for login security, and you will most likely find a setting has been added somewhere you "never thought to look"

Comment: Thanks - I've looked what you've said up and applied it to my personal knowledge-base (brain).  I've worked in a 2003 domain for far too long (that's long enough ago right?)  We're actually only now updating the DCs.